# Why TypeScript errors on properties that are maybe exist, and just accepts values that existing for sure?

Tags: typescript

See the following example:

```
const a = {
    a: 1,
    b: 1
};

const b = {
    b: 1,
    c: 1
};

const all = {
    a, b
};

type Keys = "a" | "b"

Object.keys(all).map((key) => {
    const value = all[(key as Keys)];
    const { a, b, c } = value;

    return { ...{ a, b, c } };
})
```

For `a` and `c` it throws errors because they aren't exist in all possible cases.

Shouldn't:

```
{
    a: number;
    b: number;
} | {
    b: number;
    c: number;
}
```

actually mean:

```
{
  a?: number;
  b: number;
  c?: number;
}
```

?

Link: [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gWAFA2-AXDARgBpMcYAjfAzAXwG5NNRJZylVSdLCSsdgqtBhibho8ADYT26PtjhEKQxhigBPAA4BTGAGktaiOwBEcYzAA+MY+WMqA8uQBWW4FAB0AawMQAFHCkASncAWzgNX19vNUCkAD4OORhmcRR4RXJFYBgadgCJAG0og3gjfUNAgF1hTmwAJy0oAFc6sFQYd060hQos3JpaQKA)

Comment: This is explained in the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types

Comment: You also want to read the chapters following it regarding type guards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these two cannot mean the same, they have some intersection though. Consider

```
type A = {a: string} | {b: string}
```

```
type B = {a?: string, b?: string}
```

The difference is that `A` allows only on object with key `a` or key `b`, valid object of this type cannot have both or none keys. The second `B` is wider type, it allows on everything type `A` is allowing plus `{a,b}` and even `{}`. We can have a prove at the type level about such relation between these two types.

```
type AIsSubTypeB = A extends B ? true : false; // true
type BIsSubTypeA = B extends A ? true : false; // false
```

What above means is in every case type `B` is needed, type `A` can be used instead, as type `A` is more strict type `B`, in other way around it is not true.

To see more clear the difference we can write the second as union also, consider:

```
type A = {a: string} | {b: string}
type B = {a: string} | {b: string} | {} | {a: string, b: string}
```

The intersection between `A` and `B` is visible now, it is exactly `{a: string} | {b: string}`, and its equal to type `A` what also means that type `A` is a subset of type `B`.

So the answer is - no these two definitions are different and my simplified example applies to types in the question.